# Is it possible to create new ASP.NET directives?

Tags: asp.net

You know how ASP.NET pages typically begin with a Page directive setting certain properties and behaviors for the page? Looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ContactUs.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContactUs" %>
```

The whole list of currently available directives is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7.aspx

**Does anyone know if it is possible to create new directives?**

For example, I'm using reflection to do certain things with pages on the site and I decorate their class declarations with custom attributes. I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow do that even when there isn't a code behind or designer file to find such a class declaration, and all the scripts for the page are in the script tag that's run on the server side.

P.S. I'm aware that I could use the Page directive to set the base class and then also use it to set inherited properties. However, there can be *0 - n* of these attributes, so that couldn't be done elegantly.